# Mounting long pipe as curtain rod from ceiling between exposed beams. What are these hex bolt sleeves used for existing pipes / better alternative?

Tags: pipe, mounting

I live in a loft space with exposed beams ~9ft apart and vaulted ceilings. I'm trying to cordon off part of the space with a divider curtain. I previously tried a tension rod which sagged too much due to the span length, so now I'm trying to figure out how to mount some sort of pipe between the beams that I can then put a curtain with 1.5" diameter grommets on. After many hours of combing the hardware store, I still can't find something that seems like it will solve my issue.

Floor flanges for pipe that I can find all seem to be threaded, so even if I could cut a pipe to the exact length between the beams, I would be losing the threading and thus unable to attach them on one end. I can't find any other option that would allow me to just go straight across between the beams (I'm all ears if there is one as this seems the ideal way to do it!), so my other option would be the ceiling. From the ceiling I need to come down around 12-14 inches to clear an exposed sprinkler pipe.

There are two issues I'm having here. While the thinner (~3") pieces of wood that run perpendicular to the beams might just barely be wide enough to attach a floor flange, two pieces of pipe and two elbows for a U shape, all except the very last one closest to the wall are at an angle due to the vaulted ceilings. Additionally, were I to go this route, I'm not sure what I need screw-wise to ensure the weight is accounted for. I used lag screws with a hex head for a projector mount once, but I'm not sure how long these ought to be and lag screws don't seem to be the correct width for the flange holes regardless.

The other option that appears to have been used for the existing sprinkler pipe seems to be sinking some sort of hex shaped sleeve with a threaded inside into the wood (no idea what this is called). Into that sleeve a long bolt comes down and on the end is a clamp with short bolts on each side that allow the bottom to come off so the pipe can be sandwiched between that and the part attached the the bolt. This would probably work except that I can't figure out what any of these pieces are, especially the thing that goes into the wood.

After stubbornly spending most of the day trying to accomplish what I initially thought would be a very straightforward task, I'm hoping someone can suggest a solution either by suggesting something I haven't thought of, or identifying the pieces I can't figure out since I'm presently pretty frustrated and stumped.

Many thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you google 'pipe hangers' you'll find tons of options.  Here's the relevant section of the McMaster catalog: https://www.mcmaster.com/pipe-hangers

Comment: Dont F with a community water system, if a fire system good luck . !!!!

Comment: @EdBeal I'm not trying to I'm trying to do something similar to hang another pipe, but I don't know what the parts are.

Comment: Ok I agree and upvote for jsotola’s answer, it sounded different while reading at first and after having to call in a certified pipe fitter on a 3 story multi family dwelling because a renter was trying to raise the ceilings and the pipes were in the way I went there. Very expensive and a lot of water damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called a `rod coupling nut`.

[image]

The part above it is a `double ended wood screw threaded rod stud`, or something like that

[image]

Or you can buy a `vertical threaded rod hanger`

[image]

Comment: thank you!  Looks like I need a stud driver if that's the case, or a nut driver may work with the other one.

Comment: you do not need a special tool ... put the coupling nut on the stud ... thread a regular bolt into the other end of the coupling nut ... use a socket wrench to screw the stud into wood ... use a crescent wrench to hold the coupling nut and remove the bolt with the socket wrench

Answer (score 0):

The sleeve piece you asked about may be a threaded insert (photo from https://www.ezlok.com/threaded-inserts-for-wood):

[image: threaded insert]

The "long bolt" is called threaded rod or all-thread.

The clamp piece for the pipe is called a pipe hanger. As you'll see if you do an image search, there are a multitude of styles available.

I couldn't quite work out a mental image of the space you're working with -- a sketch or photo would help. In general, though, if your curtain rod is sagging then you need intermediate support, lighter curtains, narrower span, or a larger curtain rod.

Regarding the floor flanges: in many cases you'd have to thread the flange onto pipe first, then bolt the flange into place. If you feel a need to choose bolts that don't fit through the holes, drill the holes to a larger size.

Comment: I added some pictures for clarification.  If those are them there's another piece too.

Answer (score 0):

Try hooks on the angles of the vault. Then you can hang rope/cable with only another hook or two to support the center. If you are hanging curtains, place the hooks where two panels met.

Look for threaded bridle rings for the middle so you can fuss with it easier.
[2 inch Bridle Ring from ShowMeCables.com](https://www.showmecables.com/2-inch-bridle-ring-threaded?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI9sXYts_z5gIVxZyzCh2-KQWPEAQYAiABEgJOqPD_BwE)

Answer (score 0):

From your description the sprinkler pipes are hung with rod hangers in the ceiling, and pipe hangers in the rod hangers.  That would work fine but you wouldn't be able to slide the curtain past the pipe hanger.

If you want to suspend the pipe from beam to beam, you could use EMT - thinwall metal electrical conduit, normally used for wiring, available at any home improvements store or electrical supply.  To minimize sag, you'd probably want to use the largest size that will fit your hardware.  Trade size 1" EMT is about 1-3/8" outside diameter, so that ought to work.  It's sold in 10' lengths so it will span between your beams.

You can use **EMT set screw connectors** on the ends of your pipe

[image: EMT set screw connector]

EMT connectors are available and inexpensive anywhere conduit is sold.  These would give you the threads you want to go into the floor flanges.  The threads should mate up fine.

You just have to trim the EMT to the right length before assembling everything.  Easiest way would be to assemble everything before trimming, make sure it's all snug, and measure the overall length;  subtract the width between beams from the overall length, that's how much you have to cut off the EMT.  Remove one of the connectors, and trim the pipe by that result, reassemble, and hang it between the beams.

Another alternative, even cheaper and easier solution would be to use two EMT hangers at the ends of the conduit:

[image: EMT hanger]

You would cut the conduit to just a hair shorter than the distance between beams;  screw the hangers into the wood ceiling right near the beams;  and install the conduit in the hangers.  The hangers are about a buck so this would be a <-$10 and <-10 minute project, the best kind.